# How to fully remove chromium browser

Tags: windows, chromium

In trying to remove Chromium. I found several instances in Regedit and removed them....but I found two more and was unsure if it was ok to remove them.

They are attached.   The Chromium page no longer loads, but I was wondering if the two following entries should be deleted:

[image: hkey_classes_root]

Answer (score 1):

If you've uninstalled the software, then you can always run a registry cleaner like CCleaner.

However, I would suggest being very careful when editing the registry keys, because you can easily create more problems for yourself later.

I know it's not the answer you are looking for, but unless there's a guide out there that will give you steps to take for Chrome (Chromium), i would uninstall the program, run a registry cleaner, and leave it at that.  Most orphan keys and files are not going to cause a lot of trouble anyways, and are generally there for a reason.  So if you remove one that is shared by other programs or Windows, it will create more problems than it will fix.

Because I don't know your level of knowledge with computers, I will also point out being an expert does not exempt you from making mistakes like that.  At some point, we could all make that 1 mistake. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a *complete* set of things, but you should at least:

- Go to `C:\Program Files`.
- Delete the Chromium folder.
- Go to `C:\Program Files(x86)` if it exists.
- Delete the Chromium folder.
- Click on Start -> `Run` (or hit <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
- Type `%AppData%`
- Delete the Chromium folder.
- Open another `Run` dialogue
- Type `%LocalAppData%`
- Delete the Chromium folder.
- Delete The Shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

When I had Chromium on my computer, I went in the files to uninstall it, but it was still messing with my computer.

What I had was a bootleg version, which is what you may have. Running a cleaner might work, but what I did was made a folder for Chromium /manually/ then I deleted it. For some reason, it worked.